# How to handle out-of-range values? Switch or if statements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have a set of test scores with values  ranging from  10 to 990. I want to place each score in a specific range.

Here is the script I've used:

```
function between(x, min, max) {
  return (x >= min && x <= max);
}

var overallScore = 960;

if(between(overallScore, 905, 990))  {
  var output = "905 - 990";
}
if(between(overallScore, 785, 900))  {
  var output = "785 - 900";
}
if(between(overallScore, 605, 780))  {
  var output = "605 - 780";
}
if(between(overallScore, 405, 600))  {
  var output = "405 - 600";
}
if(between(overallScore, 255, 400))  {
  var output = "255 - 400";
}
if(between(overallScore, 10, 250))  {
  var output = "10 - 250";
}

alert(output);
```

This works OK, provided the overallScore value is within the range 10 to 990, values outside this return the range as "10 - 250". What would be the best way to deal with this? I thought of using a switch statement but I'm having trouble seeing how this might be done. I would very much welcome any comments or help.

Comment: Scores can't be 901, 902, 903, or 904? Or 781, 782, 783, or 784? Etc.?

Comment: you should use if ,else if

Comment: @RoyS: "Excluded" as in "they can't happen" or "I want them to give the same out-of-range output as < 10"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes those values are excluded. I should have mentioned that above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as in "can't happen"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, see http://wie.ac.nz/TOEICconversion.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually use an object containing your ranges, and then make a simple function to check against them. That way it is much easier to maintain, simpler to understand.

```
var ranges = [
  { min: 10, max: 250},
  { min: 255, max: 400},
  { min: 405, max: 600},
  { min: 605, max: 780},
  { min: 785, max: 900},
  { min: 905, max: 990}
];

function getScoreRange(score){
  var output = 'out of range'; //set to either empty or null or default value for out of range scores.
  ranges.forEach(function(range){
    if(score >= range.min && score <= range.max){
      output = range.min + ' - ' + range.max;
    }
  });
  return output;
};
alert(getScoreRange(960));
```

Now you can change your logic with ease, and add new ranges or change them without changing too much, you can also reuse your scoring method with other ranges and for other purposes as well.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/workingClassHacker/c06pq2w0/3/

Comment: Thanks mate. Nice, elegant solution I hadn't thought (or knew about) using objects in this way. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simply declaring `var output` before `if-blocks`

```js
function between(x, min, max) {
  return (x >= min && x <= max);
}
var overallScore = 6000;
var output = ""
if (between(overallScore, 905, 990)) {
  output = "905 - 990";
}
if (between(overallScore, 785, 900)) {
  output = "785 - 900";
}
if (between(overallScore, 605, 780)) {
  output = "605 - 780";
}
if (between(overallScore, 405, 600)) {
  output = "405 - 600";
}
if (between(overallScore, 255, 400)) {
  output = "255 - 400";
}
if (between(overallScore, 10, 250)) {
  output = "10 - 250";
}
console.log(output);
```

Your last `var` was getting executed when the variable hoisting happens before the execution of the method starts.

Comment: @Mahi yes, OP's question is `values outside this return the range as "10 - 250".` I have explained why it is happening.

Comment: he said it's working fine .is their any other solution to get the result ?

Comment: @Mahi it doesn't work fine, if you give input as 6000, it still outputs `10-250`

Answer (score 0):

You've said values like 901, 782, etc., can't happen; that means we can disregard them and do the usual thing, which is to just use `if`/`else if` with a final `else` at the end:

```js
function check(overallScore) {
  var output;
  if (overallScore > 990) {
    output = "too high"; //...whatever you want for too high...
  } else if (overallScore > 900) {
    output = "905 - 990";
  } else if (overallScore > 780) {
    output = "785 - 900";
  } else if (overallScore > 600) {
    output = "605 - 780";
  } else if (overallScore > 400) {
    output = "405 - 600";
  } else if (overallScore > 250) {
    output = "255 - 400";
  } else if (overallScore > 9) {
    output = "10 - 250";
  } else {
    output = "too low"; //...whatever you want for too low...
  }
  console.log(overallScore + ": " + output);
}
check(1000);
check(5);
check(200);
```

No need for the `between` function.

If the range really has gaps, then you still use `if`/`else if` but add the lower boundaries (perhaps with your `between` function):

```js
function between(x, min, max) {
  return (x >= min && x <= max);
}

function check(overallScore) {
  var output;
  if (overallScore > 990) {
    output = "too high"; //...whatever you want for too high
  } else if (between(overallScore, 905, 990)) {
    output = "905 - 990";
  } else if (between(overallScore, 785, 900)) {
    output = "785 - 900";
  } else if (between(overallScore, 605, 780)) {
    output = "605 - 780";
  } else if (between(overallScore, 405, 600)) {
    output = "405 - 600";
  } else if (between(overallScore, 255, 400)) {
    output = "255 - 400";
  } else if (between(overallScore, 10, 250)) {
    output = "10 - 250";
  } else {
    output = "too low"; //...whatever you want for too low
  }
  console.log(overallScore + ": " + output);
}
check(1000);
check(5);
check(200);
```